# Egit pull failure showing error

Tags: repository, egit, pull

I am facing problem with egit pull option.I can do push in my repo but cannot do pull from the repo. It comes with an error can anyone tell me the full process of pull.After googling i came to know something about fetch but from the site i am not completely aware of the use of it.When i selet team->pull  eclipse show me this:"The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration".Help me?

Comment: To prevent this from happening in the first place, the problem was that the push did not set the upstream (and didn't guide the user in that). See this bug for an idea for improving this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382190

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this answers your question.

[The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820668/the-current-branch-is-not-configured-for-pull-no-value-for-key-branch-master-mer)

Also if you have command line GIT then you should also be able to do `git branch --set-upstream BRANCH-NAME REMOTE-BRANCH-NAME` that should set up the remote tracking also.