# Git Pull: EGit with GitHub

Tags: github, branch, egit

I followed the tutorial http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial to setup EGit with GitHub. When I want to pull I had the same problem described here: [The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820668/the-current-branch-is-not-configured-for-pull-no-value-for-key-branch-master-mer)

When I add the following to .git/config

```
[branch "master"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/master
```

I get another error:

The current branch is not configured for pull
No value for key remote.origin.url found in configuration

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you also have a `[remote "origin"]` section containing a `url = ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mention in [bug 352687](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352687), this is probably because the remote section of your git config file doesn't include an '`origin`' remote.

See the ["Adding a Remote Configuration " section](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Adding_a_Remote_Configuration) of the Egit User Guide:
If you don't have a remote "`origin`", you can add one.

[image: add remote]

(this example defines a new remote "`pushtofile`", but, again, you can define one named "origin" if you didn't have one yet.)

Comment: The screenshot is different from EGit in Kepler, where radio buttons instead of checkboxes are used. So only Push or Fetch configure at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Full .git/config file should be like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://gitlab.funshion.com/gitlab/sandbox/try-conflict-resolution.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```