# Eclipse EGIT: Current branch not configred for pull

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am working on a tilebased RPG with a friend of mine who has to go away for weeks and we decided it was time to use version control/git. I am starting to regret that. After a few hours we managed to get it working to the point where:

1. I create a repository on github, add him as collaborator.
2. I commit project in eclipse to git, push
3. He pulls, gets it imported in his workspace
4. I make some changes, commit push, he pulls the changes.
5. He makes some changes, commits and pushes successfully. Changes appear in [repo](https://github.com/arynaq/KLT)
6. I try to pull changes, get errors (see image), unsuccessful.
7. I make some changes, try to commit, get errors, unsuccessful.

Essentially we are locked with a project he can update and I cannot. I am the repo owner if that matters at all.

On trying to "Fetch from upstream":
[image: "1"]

On trying to "Pull":
[image: "2"]

On commit&push:
[image: "3"]

We are pretty much stuck now. We rather not use skype to send files, at some point we are going to be professionals and that seems too tedious.

As requested: 
[image]

Comment: The images were resized? If you wish to see a larger image, copy img url and go there.

Comment: expand completely the KLM project in "Git Repositories" view, then attach the screenshot pls

Comment: We have got this working by deleting the project from both computers and cloning again, everything else failed (including a variety of suggestions on google/SO).

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8820668/247542.

Answer (score 13):

The error message "This branch is not configured for pull" in EGit is typical of a branch created locally and pushed.

That wouldn't set the merge section of that branch.
See "[The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key `branch.master.merge` found in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9711056/6309)"

```
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

To solve that, one way is to rename your current `master` branch, and, in the `Git Repositories` view:

- Right-click on "`Branches`" / "`Switch to`" / "`New Branch`"
- pull down "`Source ref`" list, select "`master`" branch (**pull strategy** "`merge`", "`Checkout new branch`" checked)
- click "`finish`"

The new branch should be correctly configured

Comment: I had seen that SO question before I posted and tried what you are suggesting but it did not work.

Comment: @user948652 what does git config returns within your repo? Do you see a section merge for master?

Comment: I tried this and it would not let me saying 'branch already exists' (locally). I switched to another branch, deleted my local branch in question, then re-checked from origin, and it worked great.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in Eclipse IDE with EGit:

```
    Open Window->Show view->Other->Git->Git Repositories
    Right click on your repo in Git Repositories view -> Properties
    Click "Add Entry..." button
    key: branch.master.remote
    value: origin
    OK
    Click "Add Entry..." button
    key: branch.master.merge
    value: refs/heads/master
    OK
    Right click on your repo -> Pull
```

Btw. I'm pulling master from remote and my local branch when pulling is also master.