# Integrating Eclipse and GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github

I am in need of help in trying to setup Eclipse so that I can push my code onto my GitHub account. I've searched online and the tutorials I have found are either outdated or don't work for me.

I already have a project on Eclipse. How would I put that code onto GitHub? Would someone please add detailed instructions please. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
As soon as I posted this question, and fiddling around with the settings I managed to get it to work! What a coincidence...

The only problem I have now is how do I set it up so that when I commit it will only select the files in the project folder? Right now it is showing all 600 files in the Package Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Alright, there are several ways of doing this. I found this to be the easiest way:

First, set up SSH2 configurations. Go to `Windows`->`Preferences`->`General`->`Network Connections`->`SSH2`->`Key Management` and `Generate RSA Key`. `Save Key`

Copy that key. You will need to go to your GitHub account settings and add the new SSH key to your account.

Now, you need to install eGit:

[image]

[image]

Next, you want to add the Git Repositories view:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Create a new Git Repository. I have already created a repository called `Java`. I will refer to that repo for the rest of the explanation.

[image]

After you create your repository, it should show up in the Git Repositories view. Now to add your project to the repository, right click on your project and select Team->Share Project.

Select the repository you just created. You can also use CTRL+ to select multiple projects and place them in one repository.

Now go back to your Git Repositories view. Go to **Remotes** . Right click and select Create Remote.

[image]

**Select `Change...` and enter the SSH link for your Repository on GitHub. 
For connection, select SSH. Then press Finish.
[image]
For Rev-mapping, select `Advanced...`. 
For `Source Ref` select `refs/heads/master`. And then press `Add Spec`, then select `Save specifications in 'origin' configuration. Then press finish.
That's pretty much it. You can commit changes by right clicking your project - >`Team`->`Commit...`**

[image]

**Push new commits to GitHub:**

[image]

This is a really good explanation on how to set up Eclipse pull requests.

[The current branch is not configured for pull No value for key branch.master.merge found in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820668/the-current-branch-is-not-configured-for-pull-no-value-for-key-branch-master-mer)