# Clone a GitHub Repository in Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0) on Windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, windows-7

I am kinda new to cloning GitHub repository using Eclipse.

One can open the GitHub Project repository from Eclipse using Git view (Window->ShowView->Others...->Git).

After cloning the GitHub project on my local working set folder, I am not able to find any Java Code file or project files under Package Explorer pane.

Here are the steps I am following:

**Step 1:** I created a local git repository which has working copy of my Eclipse Java Project.

**Step 2:** Then I synced it up to GitHub. I can see my repository in GitHub

**Step 3**: Next I tried to clone it on to my working set folder in Eclipse using Git View by using GitHub repository URI ( working set is a different local folder for my java project. It is not the same folder as my local master repository. Essentially I kind of downloaded my project files from GitHub in to working set folder on local drive)

**Step 4**: I clicked on "Git Repositories" pane

**Step 5:** Now I was expecting to see the Java Project loaded in the upper left top of the Eclipse Luna in the Package Explorer area.  I see   on the top section in the Package Explorer.

However I do not see any Java project in the Package Explorer area.I only see empty "Other projects" Working set. What must be going wrong ?

Comment: Found an answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473308/integrating-eclipse-and-github

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also faced same problem. I have followed following steps to resolve this issue:

1. Select workset in which you wants to clone project
2. Right click on workset > Click "Import" option
3. A small window will be open name "Import".

   Go To Git Option and expand it. Then click "project from Git" and click next.

   or

   just type "Project from Git" in filter text box then select "Project from Git" and click next.
4. Use "GitHub" if project cloning from GitHub else use "URI"
5. Next ... Configurations ....
6. In the end you may get option to select workset.
   Then Finish

If still not contains project, refresh workset.

Remember: In workspace, project should not contains same name as GitHub project. Only new/different name project will be check out.